# What is the difference between `.` and `#` in the JavaDoc?

Tags: java, javadoc

I have this line in Javadoc above method:

```
* {@link client.navigator.URLManager.newToken(NavigationToken)}
```

and Intellij IDEA analyzer highlights it as error:

> Cannot resolve symbol 'client.navigator.URLManager.newToken'

but if I change `.` to `#` it is ok.

```
* {@link client.navigator.URLManager#newToken(NavigationToken)}
```

What is the difference? Because I have a lot of places with `.` and with `#` in the project.

Comment: `client.navigator.URLManager` is the full path to the class, including its package named `client.navigator`. As if you would import it in your code, like `import client.navigator.URLManager;`. `newToken` however is a method, the Javadoc standard says to use `#` to separate the class and its method.g

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`.` separates parts of the package and the package from the class.

`#` separates class names from fields, methods or constructors.

I.e. in `client.navigator.URLManager#newToken` the `client.navigator` is a package, `URLManager` is a class and `newToken` is the method name.

One can even use `#someMethod` to refer to methods inside the current class without specifying the class (same for fields, ...).

Note that in the case of inner classes there will be multiple class names: `java.lang.Thread.State` is an inner class in the package `java.lang` that's inside `Thread` and is named `State`. There's no syntax difference between inner classes and top-level classes, the only way to recognize this difference (without looking up the classes) is to see that `Thread` is capitalized and therefore probably a class (but Java allows lower-case classes and upper-case packages, even if conventions forbids them).

Answer (score 0):

Javadoc generation pays attention to the `"."` and `"#"` characters when building links. Links can point to other Javadoc pages or to a location within a specific Javadoc page.

For example, here's an example of `"#"` from `Integer` which includes this Javadoc directive: `{@link java.lang.Integer#toString(int)}`. When Javadoc files are generated, that "link" directive will evaluate to HTML that points to the `toString()` method on the "Integer" .html page (specifically this: `https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#toString--`), so you can [go right there](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#toString--):

```
/**
 * Returns a {@code String} object representing this
 * {@code Integer}'s value. The value is converted to signed
 * decimal representation and returned as a string, exactly as if
 * the integer value were given as an argument to the {@link
 * java.lang.Integer#toString(int)} method.
 *
 * @return  a string representation of the value of this object in
 *          base&nbsp;10.
 */
public String toString() {
    return toString(value);
}
```

Here's another example with just `"."` characters (no `"#"`), from [`String`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/String.html) which has a link (`{@link java.text.Collator}`) which generates a URL (`https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/text/Collator.html`) that goes to [the top of the page for java.text.Collator](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/text/Collator.html):

```
 * The class {@code String} includes methods for examining

...

 * <p>Unless otherwise noted, methods for comparing Strings do not take locale
 * into account.  The {@link java.text.Collator} class provides methods for
 * finer-grain, locale-sensitive String comparison.

...
```